# creating a partition P for a proof

Tags: real-analysis

I am working on my real analysis homework and have come across a problem

$\text{if a function} f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \text{is bounded and nonnegative, prove that} \underline\int^b_af \geq 0$

I know the first step has got to be creating a partition P for this function, but I'm not really sure how to construct one in a proof. Any tips would be appreciated as this is the hardest part for me in proof writing.

Answer (score 0):

Any partition should work. Just show that the lower sum is greater than or equal to $0$ for any partition. Then you're done taking Supremum and using ordering.